# Hibernate sequence doesn't generate consecutive numbers for the primary key id during update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring boot application with spring data and hibernate to save data to MySQL database. I have a user table and an address table with one too many relationship. When I save the data the autogenerated primary key is generated correctly but when I update the address table(add a second address to the user) the primary key which is generated for the second user is not consecutive.

These are my entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq")
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;
    @Unique
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastname;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> address;
    private Boolean active;
    private String mobile;
    private String home;

    public User() {
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "address_generator", sequenceName = "address_seq")
    @Column(name = "adress_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

This is the update method

```
   @Override
    public UserDTO updateUser(UserDTO userDto) {

          User user = userMapper.getUserEntity(userDto);
          user.getAddress().forEach(a->a.setUser(user));
          User updatedUser = userRepository.save(user);
          return userMapper.getUserDTO(updatedUser);
    }
```

This is my payload. Address with id=2 is already saved and I add a second address.

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "test@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "lana",
        "lastname": "Lee",
        "address": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "street1": "344",
                "street2": "abcd",
                "city": "mycity"
            },
            {
                 "street1": "7",
                "street2": "cde",
                "city": "mycity"
            }
        ],
        "active": false,
        "mobile": "1232211441"
    }
```

when I update the this is what the id column of address table looks like. Address of the newly added address is 52 instead of 5.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the default allocation size which according to the [SequenceGenerator Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#allocationSize()) is set as:

> allocationSize
>
> public abstract int allocationSize (Optional)
>
> amount to increment by when allocating sequence numbers from the
> sequence.
>
> **Default: 50**

Try to set it to 1 or whatever suits your needs.